# How to Pass a sqlplus parameter from shell script to sql file

Tags: sql, shell

I am having a Shell script that has a variable storing the **date** value using sqlplus connection as below. I want to pass the shell variable 'var_Date' value to the sql file.

## cat extract.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh
var_Date=`sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_SID << EOF
SELECT MAX(SAMPLE_DATE)-1 FROM SAMPLE_CASES WHERE KEY IN ('ab','bc');
EXIT;
EOF`
export var_Date
echo $var_Date

sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_SID @data_extract.sql $var_Date
```

## cat extract.sql

```
set echo off
set trimspool on
set pagesize 0
set colsep ~

spool extract.csv
SELECT CASE_ID FROM SAMPLE_CASE1 WHERE TIME_START>='&1'
spool off
```

I have tried to execute this script but it is failing with **invalid identifier**. Please help to understand what is the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Please quote the full error. It should at least mention a related line number.

Comment: I am getting ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: just a suggestion why didn't you use one query such as this: `SELECT CASE_ID FROM SAMPLE_CASE1 WHERE TIME_START>=(SELECT MAX(SAMPLE_DATE)-1 FROM SAMPLE_CASES WHERE KEY IN ('ab','bc'))`

Comment: Hi change198, thanks for suggestion. The reason why I would not be able to use above suggestion is that, I am storing value max(sample_date)-1 output from another DB. Hence please advise on passing the variable value from shell script inside sql file.

Comment: Could anybody help on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in the internet for almost a week, could arrive at a working code. Below is the working code.

**cat extract.sh**

```
#!/bin/ksh
   var_Date=`sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_SID << EOF
   SET HEADING OFF
   SELECT ''''||TRIM(MAX(SAMPLE_DATE)-1)||'''' FROM SAMPLE_CASES WHERE KEY IN ('ab','bc');
   EXIT;
   EOF`
   export var_Date
   echo $var_Date

   sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_SID @data_extract.sql $var_Date
```

**cat extract.sql**

```
set echo off
set trimspool on
set pagesize 0
set colsep ~

spool extract.csv
SELECT CASE_ID FROM SAMPLE_CASE1 WHERE to_char(TIME_START,'DD-MON-YYYY') >='&1'
spool off
```

Firstly, we to need to pass the argument $var_Date to sqlplus within single quotes which is done within the variable declaration itself by concatenating ''''. We also need to use SET HEADING OFF to make the variable var_Date hold only the date value and not the header value.

Secondly, there was a ora error: "**ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected**". To mitigate this, I had type-casted the field time_start to to_char post which the filter is applied and stored in the csv file.

Hope this helps others who had trouble like me.